# Issue in Resteasy Tomcat deployment

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to deploy the Resteasy webservice application in Tomcat 6.0 but it is giving me error in catalina.out

```
    INFO [main] (Log4jLogger.java:82) - Adding scanned resource: com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx
    DEBUG [main] (Log4jLogger.java:60) - Unable to retrieve ServletContext: expandEntityReferences defaults to true
    DEBUG [main] (Log4jLogger.java:60) - Unable to retrieve ServletContext: expandEntityReferences defaults to true
    Feb 22, 2013 12:24:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    Feb 22, 2013 12:24:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Context [/xxxxxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
```

My web.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>resteasy</display-name>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.document.expand.entity.references</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What is probably going wrong here?

The Resteasy code which is throwing this error is line 47-61 in https://github.com/ronsigal/Resteasy/blob/1ddd469a1ddcf51796f1926477903915e41e94b8/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/DocumentProvider.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this error was not related to the `DocumentProvider`. I checked the localhost.log and it was missing an **slf4j-api.jar** which I forgot to copy and RESTEasy was complaining about that.

Moral of story -- Don't forget to check localhost.log when you get this kind of error.